# asp.net code doesn't call the javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working on a project where I have to show and hide buttons based on drop down selection. Please find the attached fiddler link. My function is not getting called/nothing is happening when I select the drop down values. Any help?!

Page code:

```
<div class="span6 offset2">
<br />
<div class="row">
Location ID
<select id="iloc_Id" runat="server" class="form-control" style="width: 50%" visible="true" onchange="validate()">
<option disabled="">All Locations</option>
<option value ="1">1- Verona</option>
<option value ="2">2- Como</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Width="50%"> First Report </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Width="50%" OnClick="Report2"> Second Report
</asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function validate()
    {
        var selected_loc = $("#iloc_Id").val();
        if (selected_loc == '1')
        {
            $('#LinkButton1').show();
            $('#LinkButton2').hide();
        }
    else  if (selected_loc == '2')
        {
            $('#LinkButton1').hide();
            $('#LinkButton2').show();
        }
    else 
        {
            $('#LinkButton1').show();
            $('#LinkButton2').show();
        }
```

link: `https://jsfiddle.net/rickfiddle/5pvwznge/5/`

Comment: Check the html and inspect the actual generated front-end id's...

Comment: When I run you fiddle, I get a 'validate is not defined' error, so the html cant find the js.  Where is this function in relation to the HTML, same page or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, just need to add a closing bracket at the end

```
function validate()
{
    var selected_loc = $("#iloc_Id").val();
    alert(selected_loc);
    if (selected_loc == '1')
    {
        $('#LinkButton1').show();
        $('#LinkButton2').hide();
    }
    else  if (selected_loc == '2')
    {
        $('#LinkButton1').hide();
        $('#LinkButton2').show();
    }
    else  if (selected_loc == '3')
    {
        $('#LinkButton1').hide();
        $('#LinkButton2').hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#LinkButton1').show();
        $('#LinkButton2').show();
    }
}
```

and change the jsfiddle configuration Load Type from

```
On Load
```

to

```
No wrap - bottom of <head>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Fiddler as a tool here to show my code. What coding related change should I make so the code will work?

Comment: In that case, as mentioned before, you could add an onchange handler after your validate() function with javascript: document.getElementById("iloc_Id").onchange = function() {validate()}; Or, alternatively, with jQuery: $("#iloc_Id").change(function() {validate()});

Answer (score 1):

In the javascript code, after closing validate() function add:

`document.getElementById("iloc_Id").onchange = function() {validate()};`